# Promise reject as json

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm working on a project in react-native with laravel (php) backend. I have a class 'AuthService' with method login (username,password)  which returns a promoise, resolving the user and rejecting the errors. The errors will be responded in JSON, so that I can show the particular errors to the user, but since unexpected errors can occur, I also want to provide a json object to consuming component.

```
        return fetch(Config.AUTH_URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email, //provided
            password: password //provided
        })
    })
        .then(response=> {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json().then(user=> {
                    console.log(user);
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('auth.token', user.api_token);
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('user_name', user.user.name);
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('user_email', user.user.email);
                })
            } else {
                if (response.status == 422) {
                    //this needs to be rejected, but gives error
                    return Response.reject(response.json());

                } else {
                //when the response from server is unexpected error (eg. 500 without json data),I still want to reject with a json object
                    return Promise(null, ()=> {
                        return {"email": ["Technical problem, try later"]}
                    });
                }
            }
        }, err=> {
             throw Error({"email": ["Technische fout. Probeer het opnieuw"]});
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.then((response)=>{}) is called when the promise end up succesfully (with resolve() function) so you shouldn't call resolve function in then() function.

.catch((err)=>{}) is called when the promise fails (with reject()function )

what you need to do is handle successful responses in then and handle fails in catch.

```
.then(response=> {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json().then(user=> {
                    console.log(user);
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('auth.token', user.api_token);
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('user_name', user.user.name);
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('user_email', user.user.email);
                })
            } else {
                if (response.status == 422) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                        return {"email": ["Technical problem, try later"]}
                }
            }
        } .catch(function (err) {
           return ({"email": ["Technische fout. Probeer het opnieuw"]});
    });
```

If you want to control resolve and rejects you can use 'request' instead of fetch

```
var request = require('request');

function getUserData() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request('http://......', function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      resolve(body);
    });
  });
}

async function main() {
  try {
    var response= await getUserData();
    console.log(response);
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

take a look at this blog
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/asyncawait-the-hero-javascript-deserved.html

Comment: Thanks for the response but fetch api doesn't provide resolve callback, it only provides the response object. How can I still use reject and resolve? @Burak Karasoy

Comment: @DesterDezzods answer updated. You can use another component like 'require' it provides resolve and reject.